# Two column CSS Layout with the menu side column same hight as main content?

Tags: css, xhtml, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get two columns of the same height.

Is there a way I can make the columns the same heights as each other i.e. main body and menu column being same regardless of how much content is in either?

Using XHTML Strict 1.0.

Comment: Would help if you mentioned what you've checked out and what rules you're wary of bending. Anyway, here are two standards-compliant solutions - the CSS-Tricks treatment: css-tricks.com/super-simple-two-column-layout. And the A List Apart treatment: alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some fixed height approx. screen height and overflow: hidden for parent div.
Add overflow : auto and height:100% for main div & sidebar. So that layout doesn't break when content grows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
body                    {   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;  }
.clear                  {   clear:both; }
.container              {   background:#eee; display:inline-block; height:300px; overflow:hidden; padding:10px; width:800px;  } 
.container p,           {   color:#003;  }
.main                   {   background:#fff; float: right; height:100%; overflow:auto; padding:0 15px; text-align:justify; width:470px;  }
.main h1                {   color:#930;  }
.sidebar                {   background:#000; float:left; height:100%; overflow:auto; width:280px;    } 
.sidebar ul li a        {   color:#fff; text-decoration:none;    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link -1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link -2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link -3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <h1> Lipsum dot com </h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>

            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

            <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

            <p>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


        </div>
        <br class="clear" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have made few changes to the CSS of the page, as per below comments you can check this out

```
<style type="text/css">
body                    {   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:18px;  }
.clear                  {   clear:both; }
.container              {   background:#eee; display:block; overflow: hidden; position: relative; padding:10px !important; width:800px;  } 
.container p,           {   color:#003;  }
.main                   {   background:#fff; float: right; height:100%; overflow:auto; padding:0 15px; text-align:justify; width:470px;  }
.main h1                {   color:#930;  }
.sidebar                {   background:#000; float:left; height: 100%; left:10px;  position: absolute; width:280px; } 
.sidebar ul li a        {   color:#fff; text-decoration:none;    }
</style>
```

Comment: when I did that I got scrolling bars rather than the content columns growing releative to each other

Comment: Hi, when I tried this all I got was scrolling bars no = columns

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uYknh/

```
<div id="cols">
    <div class="col col1">
        asd<br/>asd<br/>asd<br/>asd<br/>asd<br/>asd<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="col col2">
        asd<br/>asd<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.cols{display:table-row;width:100%;}
.col{display:table-cell;width:230px;background-color:#eee;border:1px solid #555;}
```

Comment: cool any idea why when I view this via design veiw in Microsoft Expression they don't show up next to each other but one under the other as if there only 1 column?

Comment: Looks like this doesnt work for ie7 and below http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="main_body" class="custom_width"></div>
<div id="menu_column" class="custom_width"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom_width {
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Adjust the width accordingly.